# Unity Mash Collider Convex

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I wanted to turn on is Trigger by putting C-shaped mash in Unity Mash Collider.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtIug.png)
But this mash collider doesn't activate is Trigger unless Convex is turned on
When you turn on Convex, the C-shaped collider decreases the polygon and becomes dull, turning it into an O-shaped one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUWvW.png)
Is there a way to turn off Convex and use isTrigger, or is there any other way to start from scratch?

(unity 2021.3.x)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple convex colliders on children of you object to create a [Compound Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

This will allow you to make a trigger that is concave, but actually made up of multiple convex parts.